# Array being "linked" to a different array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to set an array to something, then set the value of a second array to the value of that first array. When I set the variable of the second array equal to the variable first array, though, the second array seems to just become a clone of the first array, and mimic it exactly. This is not what I want — I just want the second array to be set equal to the current value of the first array. I assume this is a basic problem, but I don't know the best way to solve it.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/7rLvQ/

```
a = [-1, -1, -1];
b = [];
while (a[2] < 10) {
    console.log(b + ", " + a);
    a[2]++;

    b = a;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the second array seems to just become a clone of the first array, and mimic it exactly

No. The point is that there is no second array any more. You just have two variables pointing to the same array.

> I just want the second array to be set equal to the current value of the first array

To do so, you'll need to create a new array and copy every item value. Fastest way is using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
 b = a.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the variables are references to the arrays, not the array themselves. Try this.

```
b = a.slice();
```